# $X,Y$ independently uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$. Find $P[XY<1/2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X,Y$ are independently uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$. Find $P[XY<1/2]$

The following is my answer:

We know the total region is a square with area $4$, centered at origin.

1. Find the region $A = \{(x,y) | xy\geq 1/2\}$. $A = \int_{1/2}^1\int_{1/2y}^1 \frac{1}{4}dx'dy'$.  (Note: Because of uniform distribution, assume the joint pdf = $k$; $4k=1 \rightarrow k=\frac{1}{4}$.
   Note: The region $A$ is the intersection of hyperbola and square in the first quadrant.
2. $P[XY<1/2]=\frac{4-2A}{4}$.  (Note: Since there are only two regions of $A$ which are in the first and third quadrant. That is to say, in the second and fourth quadrants, $xy<\frac{1}{2}$ always)

Is my concept correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. $Y$ is a random variable.

Comment: The idea is right, the limits on the integral also. You left out the computation of the integral so I cannot check that.  Good description of what you did and why. It is best not to use $A$ for both the region and the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost correct; except you're taking the factor $\frac14$ into account twice. Either $A$ is meant to be an area; then the result is correct, $\frac{4-2A}4$, but then the integrand should be $1$, not $\frac14$; or $A$ is meant to be a probability; then the integrand $\frac14$, the constant density, is correct, but then the result should be $1-2A$, not $\frac{4-2A}4$.